# way to determine how many times i can sum a subsequence to obtain a given k number in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, slice

i do have a list of int numbers; i'm trying to optimize my code and find a way to let it perform better.

I have a string of numbers, i convert that string in a list of integers and then i iterate the list through 2 for cycles to find the subsequences which sum is equal the subtotal k (this time is 9) but it won't pass all the timeout test i was given, cause is inefficient as f.
I was suggested to use dictionaries, but coming from c i'm not very prone in using them.

```
def ex1(int_seq, subtotal):


lista = convert(int_seq)
cont = 0 
lun = len(lista)

for i in range(lun):
    for j in range(i+1,lun):
        somma = sum(lista[i:j])
        if somma == subtotal:
            cont += 1
            
        elif somma < subtotal:
            somma += sum(lista[i:j])
            
        elif somma > subtotal:
            break
```

Comment: You should provide sample data and the expected output, and clarify a very important point: are all integers positive? In this case, the problem becomes much simpler.

Comment: the data are the following:

int_seq = '3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'  --> converted into a list of int
subtotal = 9 

the expected output for this is 7

also, yes, all positive integers